# bundlePath is nil but NSLog prints right path

Tags: ios, objective-c

I try to get resource from bundle inside framework. As you can see bundlePath is nil. But NSLog prints right path. And bundle is nil. Why?

[image]

Comment: mloModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Not sure why it's happening, but the code is inefficient given you get a bundle in order to allocate a new one.  This is clearly unnecessary:</strike>

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSURL *modelURL = [bundle URLForResource:... ];
```

I missed the framework-element when answering this question.  As you are calling this code from within the framework code I assume that `[NSBundle mainBundle]` is returning the bundle of the framework and not the app.

The answer lies in the app providing the framework code with the app's bundle via some method.  The framework code *should* then be able to access files within the app bundle.

Comment: I'm getting modelURL as nil and bundle is nil too. I try to check bundlePath.

Comment: I tried   NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
        NSURL *modelURL = [bundle URLForResource:@"MLO_iOS" withExtension:@"momd"]; But got nil;

Comment: @stosha Looks like `MLO_iOS.momd` is not in the app bundle then.

Comment: I checked. If I insert this code to main code (not framework). It works.

Comment: MLO_iOS.momd is in root of bundle. I checked.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @esqew No it does answer the question, however it's the wrong answer (I missed the framework-element when answering the question). The issue is that framework is its own bundle, outside that of the app, so I assume `[NSBundle mainBundle]` returns the framework bundle and not the app's bundle.

Comment: @trojanfoe can explain me how can i place my framework in main context? I need to get access to main bundle from framework.

Comment: As I mentioned in my edited answer; the app has to pass the bundle instance to the framework.  Although there may be better ways I am unaware of.